# jQuery fade image in and out on click or load

Tags: javascript, jquery

I was given this fantastic script, from @Phil, that helped get my out of a stump and it works perfectly in my application. But because I'm so new to javascript I can't figure out how to make the images animate opacity in and animate opacity out.

```
// jQuery syntactic sugar to run after page loads
$(function () {
    // attach a click event to anything with a data-file attribute
    $("[data-file]").on('click', function (evt) {
        // figure out what was clicked
        var clickedEl = $(evt.target);
        // get the data-file attribute
        var dataFile = clickedEl.attr('data-file');
        var container = $(".bom_container");
        // empty the div
        container.empty();
        // create image element
        var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", dataFile)
        // add it to the container
        container.append(img);
        // or update the background image
        // container.css('background-image','url('+ dataFile +')');
    });
});
```

When the links are clicked on, these images open in a container. But again, I would like the images to ease in instead of just BOOM APPEAR. Is there somewhere I can add animate opacity to this script or do I have to add an whole new script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery has great `.fadeIn()` and `.fadeOut()` methods just for this.

```
// jQuery syntactic sugar to run after page loads
$(function () {
    // attach a click event to anything with a data-file attribute
    $("[data-file]").on('click', function (evt) {
        // figure out what was clicked
        var clickedEl = $(evt.target);
        // get the data-file attribute
        var dataFile = clickedEl.attr('data-file');
        var container = $(".bom_container");
        // empty the div
        container.empty();
        // create image element
        var img = $("<img/>").attr("src", dataFile).css("display","none") // <----- see here
        // add it to the container
        container.append(img);
        img.fadeIn(/*duration in ms*/) // <----- see here
        // or update the background image
        // container.css('background-image','url('+ dataFile +')');
    });
});
```

Comment: This made my image not show up at all. I wonder why. I copied it exactly the way you wrote it. It seems in theory it would work.

Comment: sorry the initial style should be `display:none` instead of `opacity:0`

Comment: I made a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rxte4/1/) to demonstrate. just click the button.

Answer (score 1):

Before changing the image src you can fade out the image, change the source, then fade in the new image.

```
$('#img_selector').fadeOut('fast', function() {
   $(this).attr("src", "newsource.jpg")
   .fadeIn("fast");
});
```

Comment: Hi, @Jako. Thank you for taking the time to respond. This did not work. Maybe I shoudl be writing it more custom to what I already have.